# Where to start learning how to transform this application into a GUI?

Tags: user-interface

I am currently deployed overseas with the military and am using my down time to keep up with my civilian education, which is about 1 year of computer science. I developed this rather simple batch program that functions to use taskkill to kill a specific .exe after a specified time, aka an application-specific Sleep Timer:
[Blog post describing use of program.](http://streamingfreebies.com/blog/2012/12/pandorasleeptimer/)

However, I have never had any experience with a GUI program. I have seen some old Q&As here recommending using Qt to get started, but as things change so quickly in the technology world, would you all be kind enough to give me some fresh information on how to create a GUI out of this application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the Windows API + Windows Resource files + the C language to do it. ResEdit is a useful tool to edit resource files. Some handy links:
[Windows Application UI Development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff657751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/)
[ResEdit Home Page](http://www.resedit.net)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great resources. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Microsoft technologies coupled with Qt, you'll cut learning and dev time by learning and using tcl/tk which comes with "expect" to communicate with command line programs and utilities. The only downside is needing to deploy tcl/tk to each machine to run your program as it's not compiled, rather an interpretive language.